# recordEditForm fails to rehydrate picklist fields

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

I've noticed that recordEditForm fails to load picklist values. It saves them properly, but try to reload page and picklist fields are blank, while checkboxes and text fields are fine.

Feels like a bug right?

```
    <lightning:recordEditForm
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            objectApiName="Opportunity">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:layout >
            <lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Some_Boolean__c"/>
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Some_Picklist__c"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Even I faced similar Issue.

Its the problem of new release, So

> ```
>    <lightning:inputField>
> ```

will not work for picklist,You can raise the case for salesforce (It may take some time) or You can write custom Logic for  picklist values.